# Is it possible to only enable autolayout for some views?

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I am working on a legacy codebase which draws all the views programmatically.  As I start to bring in autolayout, I started with one simple table view and no constraint even need to be created for this table view.  However, when I run the app in iPhone 6+ simulator, that table view still got zoomed in and when I use lldb I found `<UIWindow: 0x791404e0; frame = (0 0; 320 568)` even before initializing the table view controller.

My question is how does iOS determine UIWindow frame size and whether a zoom in is necessary? Do I have to enable autolayout for ALL the views before I can see it working?

Comment: No, you need to provide the 3x launch image or app icons or something like that and then it will render you at native resolutions.

Comment: What about iPhone 6? That shouldn't require 3x launch image or app icons, right?

Comment: I dunno man, try it and see.

Comment: It's not working on iphone 6 as well.  What's puzzling me is I get `<UIScreen: 0x7a43b2f0; bounds = {{0, 0}, {320, 568}};` right after I enter `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` on an iPhone 6 simulator.

Comment: Yes; until you tell it you know about the new larger screen size, it will scale your app to the iPhone 5 screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out that I need to provide proper launch image.  iOS is determining UIScreen dimensions by the available launch image dimensions.